# MVC dynamic menu

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, menu, scroll, effect

This is my Shared Layout where I have this menu layout but IO want it to be an Dynamic menu with scrolling effect when I hover over an menu it wil scroll out and show the menu entries that are correspondig with that top menu.

```
<div>
    <div id="LHS">
        <div id="leftNavBox">
            <div class="leftNavBoxTop">
            </div>
            <div class="leftNavBoxCenter">
                @if (Model.MainMenu.ShowMaintenanceMenu)
                {
                <div class="mainmenu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a title="Maintenance" class="mainmenulinks_Sublinks" href="#">Maintenance</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div id="ViewSubMenu1">
                        <div class="submenu">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Business Partners", "Index", "BP")
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="submenu">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Services", "Index", "Service")
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="submenu">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Tariffs", "Index", "Tariff")
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="submenu">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Users", "Index", "User")
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="submenu">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Monthly Reports", "Index", "MonthlyReportFile")
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                }
                <div class="LHS_Spacer">
                </div>
                @if (Model.MainMenu.ShowMaintenanceMenu)
                {
                    <div class="mainmenu">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a title="Analyses and Reports" class="mainmenulinks_Sublinks" href="#">Analyses and Reports</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <div id="ViewSubMenu1">
                            <div class="submenu">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        @Html.ActionLink("Finance Report", "Index", "FinanceReport")
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
            <div class="leftNavBoxBottom">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="contentArea">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
```

Comment: Testing it with dynamic menu things from here have tried a java sample but sofar the onley thing it will do is make whole stie white so al other contect is suddely deleted or masked

Comment: Java? With C#? What is going on? Have you tried CSS because that should be all you need.

Comment: yes have tried it but didnt work the way i want i dont know how you come to java but i never explicitly named java as language i simpely asked how to create an dynamic menu with scrolling down effects from the base code i gave above

Comment: You said in the comment right above mine `tried a java sample`. Can you share what css you tried? You're much more likely to receive help fixing code than getting code.

Comment: well i dont see that comment but the code is comming from asp.net MVC 4 with basicly uses Jqueries and java scripting for some things but i only want a point in the right direction for an scrolling down effect menu from the code i gave plus the problem is this menu is an shared layout menu so its used in everry screen in the mvc app

Comment: and i already changed the menu to top location and its in side an table without underlinings and tabel borders that i fixed in side de CSS file.